# android seekbar with brightness issue value not change

Tags: java, android

i have a app in which brightness is save in profile. profile active when selected wifi is connected . i save the setting of brightness with `shareprefrences`.when i save and connected to wifi in the `seekbar` show value same which i set on it but its brightness does not increase or decrease which i set in setting . brightness increase or decrease only when i change it manually with `seekbar`.please tell me where i do mistake here is the code of activity.

```
public class Profile1Activity extends Activity {
    //TextViews to show details of volume and brightness
    private TextView tVBrightness, tVVolume;
    //SeekBars to set volume and brightness
    private SeekBar sbVolume, sbBrightness = null;
    //Variable to store brightness value
    private int brightness = 1;
    //Content resolver used as a handle to the system's settings
    private ContentResolver cResolver;
    //Window object, that will store a reference to the current window
    private Window window;

    EditText e1;
    Button b1;

    public static final String MyPREFERENCESSS = "MyPrefsss";

    public static final String HOMEWIFI = "homewifi";
    Context context = this;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String BRIGHTNESSS = "brightnessProfile1";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile1);

        sbBrightness = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbBrightness1);
        tVBrightness = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVBrightness);


        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed2);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but2);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCESSS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String homewifi = sharedpreferences.getString(HOMEWIFI, "");
        e1.setText(homewifi);
        sbBrightness.setProgress(sharedpreferences.getInt(BRIGHTNESSS, 0));

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String homewifi = e1.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                editor.putString(HOMEWIFI, homewifi);
                //Suhas
                editor.putInt(BRIGHTNESSS, sbBrightness.getProgress());
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(Profile1Activity.this, "Thanks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
//
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo mWifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

                if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
                    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    final WifiInfo conn = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, con.getSSID()+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if (conn.getSSID().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("\"" + homewifi + "\"")) {
                        initializeControls1();
                        sbBrightness.setProgress(sharedpreferences.getInt(BRIGHTNESSS, 0));
                    }
                }

                handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
            }
        }, 100);

    }

    private void initializeControls1() {

        //Get the content resolver
        cResolver = getContentResolver();

        //Get the current window
        window = getWindow();
        //Set the seekbar range between 0 and 255
        sbBrightness.setMax(255);
        //Set the seek bar progress to 1
        sbBrightness.setKeyProgressIncrement(1);

        try
        {
            //Get the current system brightness
            brightness = System.getInt(cResolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
        }
        catch (SettingNotFoundException e)
        {
            //Throw an error case it couldn't be retrieved
            Log.e("Error", "Cannot access system brightness");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Set the progress of the seek bar based on the system's brightness
        sbBrightness.setProgress(brightness);

        //Register OnSeekBarChangeListener, so it can actually change values
        sbBrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {
                //Set the system brightness using the brightness variable value
                System.putInt(cResolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);
                //Get the current window attributes
                LayoutParams layoutpars = window.getAttributes();
                //Set the brightness of this window
                layoutpars.screenBrightness = brightness / (float)255;
                //Apply attribute changes to this window
                window.setAttributes(layoutpars);
                run1();
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {
                //Nothing handled here
            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
            {
                //Set the minimal brightness level
                //if seek bar is 20 or any value below
                if(progress<=20)
                {
                    //Set the brightness to 20
                    brightness=20;
                }
                else //brightness is greater than 20
                {
                    //Set brightness variable based on the progress bar
                    brightness = progress;
                }
                //Calculate the brightness percentage
                float perc = (brightness /(float)255)*100;
                //Set the brightness percentage
                tVBrightness.setText("Brightness: "+(int)perc +" %");
            }
        });
    }
    public void run1(){
        String homewifi = e1.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(HOMEWIFI, homewifi);
        //Suhas
        editor.putInt(BRIGHTNESSS, sbBrightness.getProgress());
        editor.commit();
      //  Toast.makeText(Profile1Activity.this, "Thanks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem?? Be specific..!!

Comment: setting save correctly and again show correctly but value not correct

Comment: when i save brightness with seekbar at 50% seekbar show 50% but its value not change to 50% when profile active

Comment: i have 2 profile where i save brightness setting

Comment: profile active auto when selected wifi is connected

Comment: no when i call it here its not work for wifi

Comment: then its work when it change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114589/discussion-between-masoom-bacha-and-janki-gadhiya).

Answer (score 0):

set brightness also at a time you set value of seekbar in prefrance

Comment: brightness variable is your sharedpreferences brightness

System.putInt(cResolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);

Answer (score 0):

Add this code... only this much code is needed to increase and set default value of phone brightness to seekbar when your profile fragment or activity loads:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
  seekBar.setMax(255);

   float curBrightnessValue = 0;
  try {
   curBrightnessValue = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
     getContentResolver(),
     android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
  } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

   int screen_brightness = (int) curBrightnessValue;
  seekBar.setProgress(screen_brightness);
  seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
   int progress = 0;

    @Override
   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue,
     boolean fromUser) {
    progress = progresValue;
   }

    @Override
   public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // Do something here,
    // if you want to do anything at the start of
    // touching the seekbar
   }

    @Override
   public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
      android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
      progress);
   }
  });
 }
```